# Numpy array as single element of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array and an empty dataframe:

```
element = numpy.array([1,2,3])
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ["Col"])
```

I want to insert `element` in the first row of `df`. The following code:

```
df["Col"] = element
```

Gives me a dataframe 3x1 whose elements are 1, 2 and 3. I want a dataframe 1x1 whose element is the array. How can I get this result?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for specify label for set array to `DataFrame`:

```
df.loc[0, "Col"] = element
print (df)
         Col
0  [1, 2, 3]
```

---

```
df.at[0, "Col"] = element
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `element` in a list.

```
>>> df['Col'] = [element]
>>> df
         Col
0  [1, 2, 3]
```